# div width alignment is not working when menu collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material

I am using angular material and bootstrap.

In my application i have collapsible vertical menu. I have a div which have  width of

```
width: calc(100vw - 186px);
```

The above width works fine when menu bar is open. When i am closing the menu am getting some extra spaces as like below image.

[image]

When menu bar is open

[image]
I am not much familiar with CSS and html. Please help me to achieve to fit the div in screen, even menu is collapse

I have working demo in below stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-responsive-islrxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `width: calc(100vw - 186px);` the space is 186px because you have done that using `calc` and positioned `<div>` such that whenever menu open footer shifts 186px to the right .

You are shifting whole things to the right which creates this problem .

- You can either overlay the menu on content so that content will remain in its place and menu open above it (not shifting content to right) .

or

- You can use function that work when menu is open it decrease footer width by 186px and when menu is closed it will increase footer length to original size